# Laravel PostgreSQL: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I wants to get unique values from my column so i used `distinct` in my chain:

```php
$thread->comments()
            ->select(['slug', 'uid'])
            ->distinct('slug')
            ->get()
```

But postgres complains about using order by :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42P10]: Invalid column reference: 7 ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

It doesnt matter when i use `orderBy('slug')` befor or after of distinct, i will get the same error

Comment: you can't get distinct `slug` AND the uid with it in strict mode.  do a `->select(['slug'])->distinct()`

Comment: Try adding `orderBy('slug')->orderBy('uid')` to cover both selected columns

Comment: @N69S not working it say: "for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list" it doesnt matter even if i user orderBy i will get the same error

Comment: @apokryfos not working

Answer (score 2):

It is very weird and also interesting that your current Laravel syntax is somehow being interpreted as `DISTINCT ON`.  That being said, if you just want a distinct select, then you should be calling `distinct()`, with no parameters:

```
$thread->comments()
        ->select(['slug', 'uid'])
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

If you actually want Postgres' `DISTINCT ON` syntax, you might have to use a raw query, or rephrase your query another way (e.g. using a join).

```
$latestComments = DB::table('comments')
                      ->select('slug', DB::raw('MAX(uid) as max_uid'))
                      ->groupBy('slug');

$comments = DB::table('comments')
    ->joinSub($latestComments, 'latest_comments', function ($join) {
        $join->on('comments.slug', '=', 'latest_comments.slug')
             ->on('comments.uid', '=', 'latest_comments.max_uid')
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: all uid will be distinct. `distinct()` doesnt do anything in your example :)

Comment: @N69S I added a join option.

Answer (score 1):

Using a raw query:

```php
DB::select('select distinct on (slug) slug, uid from comments');
```

This will fetch a list of `slug, uid` stdClass pairs with random `uid` for each `slug`. If you want the 'biggest' uid per slug then use

```php
DB::select('select distinct on (slug) slug, uid from comments order by slug, uid desc');
```

(so much cleaner and easier to read than using a query builder)

Comment: Can you show full raw query ? becuase of  `$thread->comments()`

Comment: This _is_ the full query.  You seem to not want to use either answer for some reason.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i appreciate your work but that was too much work and confuses other developers in the peroject, Sounds like i should create a issue in laravel github

Comment: Not only is it not confusing, it would actually be _necessary_ on just about any other database besides Postgres, which won't have `DISTINCT ON`.  Then, you'd have to use my second answer, or use analytic functions.

Comment: it better i open a issue in laravel github maybe it has some issue with postgres i'm sure it will work in mysql